# "Error importing middleware" on osqa

Tags: apache-2.2, django, wsgi, middleware

I installed osqa with postgresql as backend on ubuntu 14.0.4 using the tutorial below

http://wiki.osqa.net/display/docs/ubuntu+12.04,+django+1.3,+mod_wsgi,+virtual_env,+postgresql

which asks to create a virtual environment. I did the same and was getting 500 server error. Hence, I set the debug = True in settings_local.py and got the following error in the apache error log file showing mod_wsgi errors.

```
[Mon Nov 24 11:26:33.823663 2014] [:error] [pid 6389:tid 3034110784] [remote 192.168.227.129:15031] mod_wsgi (pid=6389): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/srv/osqa.1/osqa/osqa.wsgi'.
[Mon Nov 24 11:26:33.823844 2014] [:error] [pid 6389:tid 3034110784] [remote 192.168.227.129:15031] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Nov 24 11:26:33.823882 2014] [:error] [pid 6389:tid 3034110784] [remote 192.168.227.129:15031]   File "/srv/osqa.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 250, in __call__
[Mon Nov 24 11:26:33.824027 2014] [:error] [pid 6389:tid 3034110784] [remote 192.168.227.129:15031]     self.load_middleware()
[Mon Nov 24 11:26:33.824059 2014] [:error] [pid 6389:tid 3034110784] [remote 192.168.227.129:15031]   File "/srv/osqa.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
[Mon Nov 24 11:26:33.824184 2014] [:error] [pid 6389:tid 3034110784] [remote 192.168.227.129:15031]     raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
[Mon Nov 24 11:26:33.824216 2014] [:error] [pid 6389:tid 3034110784] [remote 192.168.227.129:15031] ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware forum.middleware.extended_user: "cannot import name six"
```

I have six installed and all other dependencies installed. 
I went through the activate.py file and print **sys.path** all the paths on the virtual environment are printed as expected and mentions six path as well.
What could be the reason? 
Can anyone help me out??

Comment: In this question from StackOverflow someone had a similar problem.
I hope this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100454/no-module-named-six